# İn add product page listing categories from database

Tags: php, laravel

### Product

id
name
price 
picture
categoryId

### Category

id
name

CategoryId and Category_id are foreign key. I want to list all categories in add product page with select box using foreach. Can anyone help me? ı am new in laravel

Comment: What did you try? What you need is 'Product "belongsTo" Category' and 'Category "hasMany" Product'. Look it up on laravel docs :)

Comment: I want to do something like this. And i dont know where i will start
On your Products page; products registered in the database should be listed in the form of tables.
You should categorize your products. By type of products: category, image, product
code, product name, dimensions, description, etc. style fields (columns).
 Edit and delete the data of the products through the Products table.
It should take.
 On your Campaign Products page; Wednesdays of the week is your preference as public day the top 5 products of any category you visit, with a 20% discount It will be sold.

Answer (score 0):

In the controller, you are using for Product:-

```
public function create(){
    $data['categories'] = Category::pluck('name', 'id');
    return view('your_add_product_page', $data);
 }
```

To show all the categories in the dropdown list, in the "your_add_product_page.blade.php":-

```
{{ Form::select('categories', $categories, null, ['placeholder' => 'Select Category']) }}
```

Hope, this will help.